# Redeploy an existing Axis2 web service in remote server

Tags: apache-axis

I am trying to redeploy an Axis2 web service in a remote server. I am doing this by uploading the .aar file from the axis2 admin console.

I know 'hot update' is disabled by default. So I tried adding the following line to the services.xml file:

```
<parameter name="hotdeployment" >true</parameter>
<parameter name="hotupdate" >true</parameter>
```

However, the redeployment was not successful.

I also dont have permission to restart the server.

Can anyone let me know the right way to do this ?

Thanks!

Comment: what kind of server?  JBoss?  Something else?

Comment: its a glassfish application server

Answer (score 0):

This settings located in `axis2.xml`, You should set there.

Standalone Axis2 server:

```
$AXIS_HOME/conf/axis2.xml
```

In war file:

```
WEB-INF/conf/axis2.xml
```